# Is it possible to protect some object from some javascript run in the same page?

Tags: javascript, xss

If an attacker successfully runs some Javascript code on a page, does he have access to all the javascript objects in memory?

For example if the attacker's code runs and then we receive a JWT token using an AJAX request. Is there a way to keep a handle on that JWT token so that the attacker can't read it?

Consider the following code:

```
(function (window) {
  'use strict';

  function MyLib() {
    var _MyLibObject = {}

    _MyLibObject.retrieveJWTToken = function() {
      _MyLibObject.jwtToken = "blabla"
    }

    return _MyLibObject;
  }

  if (typeof (window.MyLib) === 'undefined') {
    window.MyLib = MyLib;
  }
})(window);
```

Once the retrieveJWTToken() is invoked:

```
var lib = MyLib();
lib.retrieveJWTToken()
```

One can easily access the JWT token by doing:

```
lib.jwtToken
```

Is there any way to design this so that this variable is only readable by MyLib to avoid a XSS using it?

Comment: question unclear, compress, bundle, minify your `js`

Comment: The term you are looking for is "closure", see https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp for an example!

Comment: @manish compressing/bundling/minifying doesn't have an impact on variables visibility

Comment: @ben probably not on the variables but `we receive a JWT token using an AJAX request` would most likely be the attack vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If an attacker successfully runs some Javascript code on a page, does he have access to all the javascript objects in memory?

As long as there is no side channel attack the attacker can only read the variables that are in the scope the script has access to.

You can create variables that are only accessable for the class/object using e.g. a [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap):

```js
(function (window) {
  'use strict';

  var tokenList = new WeakMap()
  function MyLib() {
    var _MyLibObject = {}

    _MyLibObject.retrieveJWTToken = function() {
      tokenList.set(this, "blabla");
      console.log(tokenList.get(this))
    }

    return _MyLibObject;
  }

  if (typeof (window.MyLib) === 'undefined') {
    window.MyLib = MyLib;
  }
})(window);

var lib = MyLib()
lib.retrieveJWTToken()
```

But if you request that token using AJAX, then the problem would not be protecting the variable, but protecting the request, so that a malicious script cannot intercept that request.

You can assume that if someone manages to execute a script on the page, they will be able to access the data.

They could overwrite all functions that are relevant to send or fetch data using ajax. And fetching the critical data already at that stage.

Packing scripts can be even more problematic, because depending on their configuration they allow that certain scripts are loaded later, and that can be abused.

You should focus on preventing script injection in the first place using e.g. [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP), so that scripts are allowed to be only loaded form certain domains. To restirct the `eval` rights, prevent inline scripts ensuring [Subresource Integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity)

Comment: "You can assume that if someone manages to execute a script on the page, they will be able to access the data." thanks a lot